# stubby4node comma separated query string implementation issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, stubbing, stubby4j, stubby4node

I have a URL (GET REQUEST) of the following pattern

- ^/testpath/1/test?pathid=1
- ^/testpath/1/test?pathid=1,2
- ^/testpath/1/test?pathid=1,2,5

where pathid query string parameters are comma separated

I have the following stubby mappings to match these url patterns

```
- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      pathid: '1'
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-1.json

- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      pathid: '1,2'
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-2.json

- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      pathid: '1,2,5'
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-3.json
```

but I can't get this URL mapping to properly deliver different payloads based on different parameter combinations.

- 1 -> payload1
- 1,2 -> payload2
- 1,2,5 -> payload3

how can this be done?

Comment: You might want to end `$` at the end of your regexes, or they may have unexpected results...

Comment: tried that as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to change the order of request/response mappings in the yaml file.

```
- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      **pathid: '1,2,5'**
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-3.json

- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      **pathid: '1,2'**
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-2.json

- request:
    url: ^/testpath/(.*)/test
    query:
      **pathid: '1'**
    method: GET
  response:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    status: 200
    file: response/path-1.json
```

note the path ids added in the descending order, so that more deeper matches will be executed first.

This way I was able to achieve this following requirement, of passing different path ids separated by a comma

- 1 -> payload1
- 1,2 -> payload2
- 1,2,5 -> payload3

Answer (score 1):

@Sanath, short answer - yes, stubby4j matches on different stubbed query parameters combinations.

Few questions:

1. What version of stubby4j are you running?
2. Also, are you running stubby4j as a standalone JAR or as one of the [pre-built stubby4j Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/azagniotov/stubby4j)?

I wrote a test to validate the YAML configuration you provided in your question: https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j/pull/434/files (do note, I did change the `url` a little, but it is still a regex similar to your posted YAML).

The requests that test makes do match the stubs. (I did try without `$` and with a `$`, like @code suggested). In addition, I also tested with cURL against a running standalone JAR:

```
curl -X GET  http://localhost:8882/stackoverflow/70417269/1/test?pathid=1,2,5
```

and

```
curl -X GET  http://localhost:8882/stackoverflow/70417269/1/test?pathid=1,2
```

Again, I got the expected responses from the server.

If the above does not help you, please feel free to raise a bug report https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j/issues/new/choose

Comment: I am using stubby version "5.0.0" and use it as standalone npm reference (inside a web application)

Comment: I  am using stubby4node https://www.npmjs.com/package/stubby - latest here is 5.1 to which I upgraded but still the same issue

Comment: @Sanath I see, thank you for sharing this and I think now I have a better idea what is happening. Just for the sake of visibility and clarity:

The https://stubby4j.com (a.k.a.L stubby4j) is actually a Java-based stub server, which is a separate library.

What you are using is its counterpart a NodeJS-based https://github.com/mrak/stubby4node, which I do not maintain. It is quite possible, that the features of the two libraries have diverged from each other over time. In other words, what may be working and supported in stubby4j, may not be supported in the NodeJS stubby.

Comment: @Sanath apparently someone already raised an issue 25 days ago in stubby4node about the same behavior that you are experiencing "Query parameter matching issue" https://github.com/mrak/stubby4node/issues/92